# Почему от объекта вызывается один метод, а от указателя на объект - другой метод?

Tags: c++, указатели, наследование

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void f() const;
};

void BaseClass::f() const
{
    std::cout << "In base class function\n";
}

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass
{
public:
    void f() const override;
};

void DerivedClass::f() const
{
    std::cout << "In derived class function\n";
}

int main()
{
    DerivedClass derived_object;
    BaseClass base_object = derived_object;
    BaseClass *base_object_ptr = &derived_object;

    base_object.f();//вызовет f, определённый в суперклассе
    base_object_ptr -> f();//вызовет f, определённый в наследнике
    return 0;
}
```

В консоле сначала выведется `In base class function`, а затем `In derived class function`.

Comment: Хм, наверное потому, что указатель, который приведен к базовому, физически остается указателем на наследника

Comment: А теперь посмотрите вот [сюда](https://ideone.com/Tk2U1l) и поймете вашу проблему. И еще, сравните указатели обоих объектов вашего кода, там разные указатели, а значит что вы создали копию. Т.е. `BaseClass base_object` пытается скопировать значения из `derived_object`, но там нечего копировать, и создается пустой новый объект `BaseClass`, который не имеет никакого отношения к первому объекту.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Виртуальные функции обеспечивают динамическое связывание (*dynamic binding*) и объектно-ориентированное программирование.

Решение о вызове виртуальной функции принимается на этапе выполнения программы, а не на этапе компиляции, как это происходит с невиртуальными функциями.
Но такое поведение будет поддерживаться только при использовании ссылок или указателей.

В случае

```
base_object.f();
```

`base_object` не является ни ссылкой, ни указателем. Следовательно решение о вызове функции будет принято еще на этапе компиляции (как и наблюдаем - вызывается `BaseClass::f`).

При использовании указателя все работает как задумывалось - вызывается метод из `DerivedClass`, который перекрывает соответствующий виртуальнуй метод базового класса. Каким образом это сделано - детали реализации.

**Второй момент** - это конструирование `BaseClass base_object = derived_object;`

Что происходит в этом месте? На самом деле вызывается конструктор базового класса. Это копирующий конструктор, который сгенерирует компилятор (см. [Правило трёх/пяти](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)). Он имеет сигнатуру: `BaseClass(const BaseClass&)`. Т.к. `DerivedClass` открыто наследует класс `BaseClass`, объект этого класса (`DerivedClass`) может быть преобразован к ссылке на `BaseClass`. Этим объясняется успех операции. Наглядно это можно увидеть, если объявить копирующий конструктор в `BaseClass` и сделать в нем вывод. Пример тут - https://wandbox.org/permlink/gITmHAUWMcksSeZP

Но такое явление чаще всего является неправильным, т.к. оно делает невозможным использование того самого полиморфизма, ради которого и создавались эти виртуальные методы. Это явление называют срезкой (*slicing*).

Answer (score 5):

Одним предложением: Это главная особенность полимофизма времени выполнения. Но, а если подробно...

Производный класс может неявно преобразиться в базовый, так как базовый класс является его фундаментом (при преобразовании скопируется только та часть, что лежит в фундаменте, но  в вашем вопросе это не имеет значения). Поэтому строкой:

```
BaseClass base_object = derived_object;
```

вы получаете вполне нормальный обьект типа `BaseClass`
и дальше в коде вызываете его метод.

Теперь рассмотрим указатель базового класса, который вполне может содержать адрес обекта производного:

```
BaseClass* base_object_ptr = &derived_object;
```

Каждый обьект полиморфного типа, неявно содержит указатель на виртуальную таблицу, поэтому вызывая  `base_object_ptr->f();` вызывется  виртуальный метод  обьекта `derived_object`, а не метод базового  класса. Вот если в базовом классе убрать виртуальность функции `f`,   тогда посредством указателья `base_object_ptr` вызвался бы метод базового класса, независимо от того, что он указывет на обьект производного(содержит его адрес).